# Can I use $urandom_range with time variables?

Tags: verilog, verification, system-verilog

I wanted to know if I can simply write:

```
 time time_var;
 time_var = $urandom_range (10ms, 7ms);
```

I've tried using it directly, and there are no errors/warnings issued.
However, the returned value is not between 7-10ms.
I guess it's legal to use `$urandom_range` with time literals, since I didn't receive any errors. But, why can't I get a value in the proper range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE Std (1800-2009) declares the arguments to `$urandom_range` to be of type `int unsigned` which is not the same as `time`.  I don't think you can rely on the system function to behave predictably even if you are not getting errors or warnings from your simulator.

It is a compile error in VCS and a warning with Incisive.

Can you use something like this?

```
int unsigned del = $urandom_range(10, 7);
#(1ms * del);
```